# How do you solve $\cos \pi z =0$?

Tags: complex-numbers

How do you solve $\cos \pi z =0$? I am unsure what to do with the $\pi$.
I know how to solve $\cos z = 0$, but $\pi$ is throwing me off. Can someone help start me off with this question please?

Comment: You could try the substitution $y = \pi z$? Once you know $y$, just divide it by $\pi$

Answer (score 3):

$\cos(\pi z)=0$

$\pi z=(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$

$z=\frac{2k+1}{2}$ where $k$ is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you already have the answer. If you can and have solved $$\cos(z)$$  then you have found $z$. Just divide this $z$ by $\pi$ and it will give you the solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos(\pi z)=0<=>$$
$$\pi z=\cos^{-1}(0)<=>$$
$$\pi z=\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi n<=>$$
$$z=n+\frac{1}{2}$$

(with n is the element of Z -> the set of integers)